# File.delete() fails

Tags: java

This is my code to delete a line of text from a text file. I have an add function which appends a line of text to the text file. When I delete every line of text from the text file and add back some lines of text using my add function, the delete() always fails. I checked that the file exists, and have closed everything I could and thus not sure why the delete would fail. How do I proceed to debug this problem without knowing why the delete fails?

```
{
    int currLineNum = 1;
    File temp = new File("temp.txt");

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(temp, true);
    BufferedWriter buffer = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(buffer);

    String currentLine;

   // .. loop omitted ..

    reader.close();
    printWriter.close();
    buffer.close();
    fileWriter.close();


    if(inputFile.delete()) //code fails here
        System.out.println("DELETED");
    else
        System.out.println("FAILED");

    if(temp.renameTo(inputFile))
        System.out.println("DONE");
    else
        System.out.println("NOT DONE");


}
```

Comment: What operating system? Could you have a permission problem?

Comment: Could you paste the whole source code ?

Comment: Use java.nio.file.Files.delete() to delete the file, and you should get an exception explaining the reason for the failure.

Comment: I think you are confusing between temp and inputFile, where inputFile is not physical

Comment: On slightly different note if this is something production related and not for learning, how about using commons-io?? 

No point reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).